# Error 570 - Adhaar e-KYC authentication API implemetation in PHP

Tags: php, authentication

I am trying to implement Adhaar e-kyc authentication API v1.6 (Document URL https://uidai.gov.in/images/FrontPageUpdates/aadhaar_authentication_api_1_6.pdf) in PHP using test data and credentials provided on the UIDIA portal (https://developer.uidai.gov.in/book/export/html/18). I am getting error 570 in the response which means

> Invalid key info in digital signature (this means that certificate
>   used for signing the authentication request is not valid – it is
>   either expired, or does not belong to the AUA or is not created by a
>   well-known Certification Authority)

But i am using right Staging/Testing Public Key Certificates `uidai_auth_stage.cer (Latest)` whose expiry date is 16 Sept 2020. 
Test certificate downloaded from URL (https://uidai.gov.in/beta/enrolment-update/enrolment/testing-certification.html)
I have posted my code in google groups also
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/aadhaarauth/wHBl2LU72AY

Can anyone help me on same.

Comment: Just a note that `.$aadhaar_no[0]."/".$aadhaar_no[0]` should be 0 and 1;  not that it actually makes any difference, but should be corrected all the same. Also encode your licence key (again, makes not difference). Not totally helpful, but strongly suggests you need to follow the docs more thoroughly?

Comment: Other suggestions: check return value of `openssl_pkcs12_read(file_get_contents($p12_file), $key, "public");` in case it returns "false" as you have the wrong password.

Comment: :) Who will trust Aadhar. 90% of time when I used Aadhar services, it is not worked. Just now I am faced OTP issue from EFFP-Aadhar verification. ). Why all govt sites are of same nature :D